# Check whether user belongs to sharepoint group, which consists of distribution list as members

Tags: jquery, groups

I have a distribution list, which is added to a SharePoint group. I need to determine whether the logged in user(Who is part of the distribution list) is part of the SharePoint group. this needs to be accomplished using jQuery and OOTB features. Please help.